# SignalR Connection Vs. Hub

Tags: signalr

I have to implement the real time functionality in web application. I read about SignalR that it provides two mechanism for this:

- Connection API
- Hubs

I did not find any fruitful comparison between these two across different categories such as Performance, Reliable, Security etc. Can anyone provide which mechanism should be used?

Answer (score 1):

Hub is a layer on top of Connection API. A Connection has all the logic to send/receive, connect, reconnect, raise connection errors. A Hub provides a way to send/receive strong typed messages.

Read more in http://asp.net/signalr